# Notes app performance hit

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

We recently switch to 8.5 server. We have also a quite complex application that is coming from V4.5 and was simply copied to new server versions without any issues.

But now in 8.5 we experience a performance hit when opening and create docs. As said the app has complex forms/views/scripts and I think it could be views. Is there anything to do with views when upgrading to new server versions or that may explain any performance issue ?

Comment: How recent is the server switch? It is not uncommon for the server to be busier then usual for a few days after a migration. Also have you tried upgrading the ODS of the database?

Comment: It is a small instalation. All FT indexes are updated. I will give the ODS a try.

Comment: You should also check teh view indexes (not the same as FT index). In worst case, do an UPDALL -R to rebuild all the views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance issues with "old" applications mostly come from two possible reasons:

1) Old view indices / fulltext indices / old ODS

As all of these structures improved much over the versions, there is a best practice for updating, that contains:

- compact -D to remove all View indices
- remove of all Fulltext Indices and re- create it
- updall -R -C to update the indices

2) Old compiled code (as stated before):
The (pre)- compilation of code changed during the different version. Try a "Tools -> Recompile all LotusScript" to get rid of the "old" code.

Other than that there are (very fiew) functions that where completely rewritten in the LotusScript- Enigne and could cause this degradation in performance. To find out, where the bad performance really comes from, you have to profile your code. 
Therefore you can use the Standard profiling method given by IBM ([found here](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/02042008043629WEBC4U.htm)) or use your own profiling ([like explained here](http://de.slideshare.net/CraigSchumann/bp206-lets-give-your-lotusscript-a-tuneup)).

That should help you to find the reason for your performance issues

Answer (score 3):

I've seen performance hits with old application, where a re-compilation of the LotusScript code with a newer Designer solved the issue. Guess that the design element contained object code in a format that was invalid, and that the client had to do a compile on every access.

In my particular case, it was a subform that caused the delays. Try systematically removing subforms and scripts from the main form and/or actions until the problem disappears.

Is your application using Shared Actions (they wheren't around in V4.5 (ca 1999), but might have been added later) *with LotusScript*? At least in views, they come with a performance penalty. A `@command([ToolsRunMacro])` action that calls a LotusScript agent is a lot more efficient (or at least was when I last did Lotus development).